# P vs NP, Has anyone proved there is no such thing as a collision-less one-way function.

Tags: computational-complexity, hash-function

I know that there has not been a proof against or for, the existence for a true one-way function. But i was wondering has such a thing been proven for collision-less (injective) one-way functions.

Comment: You mean, injective?

Comment: yes i will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Comment: be careful with the terms you use. "Injective" is common, but "collision-less" is non-standard and may be confused with "collision-free," which is [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function#Related_concepts).*

First, note that since what you ask is a subset of one-way functions, proving their existence would imply the existence of one-way functions. Thus, you already know that existence of injective one-way functions hasn't been established.

Now, their existence has not been disproven either: the existence of one-way *permutations* (i.e., one-way functions that are bijective, and thus *a fortiori* injective) is a common cryptographic assumption. To this day, it has not been proven nor disproven, and their existence is not known to be implied by that of one-way functions.

Comment: thank you. i knew there existence had not been proven, but i had know idea if they had been disproved.

Comment: sorry did not mean to unclick with be compressing the whole bitcoin block-chain & running a vm it gets a bit laggy.

Comment: Oh, I see. No worries.